# How to disable JRE auto update in Windows 10?

Tags: java

Windows will automatically update the JRE when Java posts new updates, but my Elasticsearch only uses jRE of the specified version, how to disable JRE auto-update in Windows system?

Comment: Fix your code. Stopping updates is like inviting malware in, and you should not do so. Any app that requires stopping updates gets an instant blacklist from every computer on my network and my persona machines. Want yours to join them on every network?

Comment: windows is not installing java updates. The JRE has its own updater.

Comment: yes, I want to disable the JRE own updates

Answer (score 4):

It is highly recommended that you **do not** disable automatic updates, as your programs can become prone to malware.  If you decide to follow through with this, the consequences are your own.

In the Java Control Panel (which you can get to from Windows' Control Panel), navigate to the `Update` tab, and verify that `Automatically check for updates (Recommended)` is **unchecked**, as seen in the image below.

[image]

Next, navigate to the `Advanced` tab and select the `Application Installation` sub-tab.  Verify that the `Never install` radio button **is ticked**, as seen in the image below.

[image]

After this, you should be good to go!

**Note**: Remember to hit `Apply` after making any changes to settings within these menus.